# Did the USA meet its goals for leading Ethiopia to invade Somalia in 2006?

Tags: united-states, somalia, ethiopia

It lead to the rise of Al Shabaab and the return of anarchy in Somalia. What was the USA aiming to achieve, and did they achieve it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is more about history than it is about politics.